# How correctly import graphviz?

Tags: python, graphviz

When I try to import graphviz package to my project I have error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'
```

I use Pycharm on Windows. I install package from `Settings -> Project Interpreter`, but error it's still the same.

I tired `python -m pip install graphviz` and `python3 -m pip install graphviz` in CMD, but without result.

My python version is: `Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "without result"? Does it not install correctly or does it not fix your problem?

Comment: @funie200 It not fix my problem.

Comment: Have to tried reinstalling the module?

Comment: @funie200 Yes, but the error is's still the same.

Comment: Run this code inside PyCharm and show us the output: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @JohnGordon the output is https://www.pastiebin.com/5e2a02e40bbc5

Comment: Based on that output, it looks like PyCharm expects to find third-party modules installed in `C:\Users\my_user\PycharmProjects\ProjectName\venv\lib\site-packages`.  Where is graphvis actually installed?

Comment: @JohnGordon It is in `venv\lib\site-packages`.
https://imgur.com/a/UdsKpcK

Comment: Did you install the Graphviz software already? The python graphviz package is just an interface

Comment: @Chasevanb How can I install it? I download zip package from `https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/` and unpack it, but I don't know what now.

Comment: @tryToRunThisCommand If you use the zip download, you'll need to set the PATH variable yourself. Otherwise, I believe the MSI installer will set the PATH variable for you: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

Comment: @Chasevanb The error is still the same.

Comment: @tryToRunThisCommand May sound silly, but is your virtual environment active?

Comment: @Chasevanb Yes, it's active.

Answer (score 2):

The Python graphviz package requires you to have Graphviz software installed. The package itself is just an interface with this software.

> The only dependency is a working installation of Graphviz ([download
>   page](https://www.graphviz.org/download/)).

source: https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html

Comment: I use `pip install graphviz` earlier. When I type it now i have: `Requirement already satisfied: graphviz in c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (0.13.2)`.